# Child Rout Params is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-ui-router

No sure what I am missing , I have a child rout and the parameter always undefined...however, it does load the right component but somehow the parameters are not being read. ( I do see the parameters on the url)

**app rout**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

// these would equal welcome component

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**search rout**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SearchComponent } from '../search/search.component';


const routes: Routes = [

    { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent,

        children: [

            { path: ':id/:name', component: SearchComponent }
        ]

    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SearchRoutingModule { }
```

**search.component** (I tried both snapshot an observable)

```
console.log('id ===========>' + this._rout.snapshot.params['id']);
        this._rout.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.log('id2 ===========>' + params['id']);

        });
```

**search.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchComponent } from '../search/search.component'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
from '@angular/forms';
import { SearchRoutingModule } from './search.routing';


@NgModule({

    imports: [HttpModule, BrowserModule,  SearchRoutingModule


    ],
    declarations: [SearchComponent],
    providers: [SearchService],
    exports: []

})
export class SearchModule { }
```

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SearchModule } from './search/search.module';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule, HttpModule, SearchModule, AppRoutingModule, CommonModule
    ],
    providers: [AppComponentService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: If you `console.log(this._rout.snapshot.params)`, is anything printed? Any change of a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: if i print (this_rout.snapshot.params) i get [object Object]

Comment: Sorry, what if you `JSON.stringify` it before logging it?

Comment: sorry not following ! what do you want me to log?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this._rout.snapshot.params))`

Comment: ahhhhhh got it ...i get {} --empty

Comment: Any chance of a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue? Will make it much easier for myself and others to debug

Comment: that will take me a while as I have so many logic in my app

Comment: It doesn't need to be the full app, just a [mcve]

Comment: So it's important to remember that routes are contextual. Depending on your route structure and which component you are requesting the routeSnapshot from that parameter may be in the parent or somewhere further up the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem being `params` not received in your `SearchComponent` is that, the `parent` route and the `child` route are both pointing to the same `component`.

Angular is loading the component for `parent` route (without params), but the url still points to the `child` route, because angular has found a route configured against it, but failed to load since it did not find any `router-outlet` inside parent.

Instead of making a `child` route, make it as a sibling route to the `parent` route. It just loads fine.

You may reconfigure your routes this way

```
{ path: 'search', component : SearchComponent, pathMatch : 'prefix'}, 
{ path: 'search/:id/:name', component: SearchComponent }
```

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-az4xeb) for your reference

EDIT :

It does work with your current routes if you add `<router-outlet>` in `SearchComponent`, but that will load same component in nest. One for parent and one for child.

Instead you can create another root component for `SearchModule` as `DummyComponent`, activating it for parent route and then load all the child components inside it.

Comment: I already tried that solution and it does work....however, I am trying to clean up the application as we have many modules and routes. I really would like to use the child becuas my next step is to use Lazy loading

Comment: If you want to keep the same configuration then you will have to add `router-outlet` inside searchComponent to load the child routes. But in that case your search component will load inside searchcomponent only. One for parent and one for child

Comment: Check updated answer and updated stackblitz demo to utilize dummy root component for your parent. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-az4xeb

Comment: I already told, you cannot point parent and child route to the same component. That is your code problem. The component being loaded is for parent route (without params), because parent route component does not have `<router-outlet>`. When you hit the child route ,the url still remains the same because, angular has found a route configured against it, but failed to load since it did not find any `router-outlet` inside parent.

Comment: Simple solution is to add root component for your parent route of `SearchModule`. And add `router-outlet` in it to load child routes, where you can see router params.

Comment: got it working, thank you sooo much for breaking this down to me. just to make sure I rapped my head around it correctly... basically every-time I have a rout with a child routes and the child rout contains a parameters that i need to use , I will nee to have (router-outlet) for the child....now, if the child rout does not have parameters I will not need to have (router-outlet) in the child as the router-outlet in the parent will be enough ..right?

Comment: router-outlet is not at all required in child component. It has nothing to do with params. router-outlet is only for parent to load the child components. Since you had the same component for parent and child, you had to add router-outlet in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ path: 'search',
    children: [
        { path: '', component: SearchComponent },
        { path: ':id/:name', component: SearchComponent },
    ]
},
```

I was able to solve the issue by doing like this